# Uploading csv file in Golang through API call ( Curl Request & python request provided)

Tags: python, csv, go, curl, http-post

I'm new to Golang and would like to upload a csv file to a website with a ***client_api_key***, ***bucket*** and ***folder***. Is there a Golang solution for this? I'm creating the csv file via Golang.

This is the curl request

```
curl --location -- request POST 'https://drivex-service.sample.com/report/api/upload' \
-- hearder 'Cookie: '89825f9123456fa0' \
-- form 'Client_api_key=vfBM-zrfumyh9WUTKGbQ=' \
-- form 'bucket=bucket1' \
-- form 'folder=ROLE/YES/FOLDER' \
-- form 'files[]=@/D:/User/example.csv'
```

Here's the python post request

```
def drivex_upload(file_obj):
        data = {
            "folder": 'ROLE/YES/FOLDER',
            "client_api_key": 'vfBM-zrfumyh9WUTKGbQ=',
            "bucket": 'bucket1'
        }
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "ContentType": "multipart/form-data"
        }
        files = {
            "files[]": file_obj
        }
        
        r = requests.post(
            self.upload_url,
            data=data,
            files=files,
            headers=headers,
            verify=False,
        )
        
        if r.status_code == 200:
            json_data = r.json()
            return r, None
        else:
            return r, "error while uploading"
```

I tried the following in Golang (not using multiparse) but am unsure of where to put the Client_api_key, bucket and folder

```
file, err := os.Create(fileName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()
writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
defer writer.Flush()
// define column headers
// write column headers
writer.Write(headers)
for key := range m {
    r := make([]string, 0, 1+len(headers))
    r = append(r, m.field1,m.field2,m.field3)
    writer.Write(r)
  }
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://drivex-service.sample.com/report/api/upload", file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
```

Will appreciate help in constructing a working Golang POST request for this!

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "net/url"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.NewRequest(
      "POST", "https://drivex-service.sample.com/report/api/upload", nil,
   )
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   f, e := os.ReadFile("file.csv")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   v := url.Values{
      "Client_api_key": {"=vfBM-zrfumyh9WUTKGbQ="},
      "bucket": {"bucket1"},
      "files[]": {string(f)},
      "folder": {"ROLE/YES/FOLDER"},
   }
   r.URL.RawQuery = v.Encode()
   r.Header.Set("Cookie", "89825f9123456fa0")
   new(http.Client).Do(r)
}
```

You should also be able to send the query string as the body, in case this doesn't
work.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#NewRequest